# What is the "state of the art" professional software for storyboards and animatics?

Tags: animation, preview

What is the "state of the art" professional software used by major Hollywood productions for storyboards and animatics?

I assume that maya would be the way the go when doing full 3D (pre-viz), right?

Answer (score 1):

Technically most of the state of the art products of animatics are made from not only 1 but many software. It all starts from visualization to animation and rendering. But no matter how excellent the tools you use if the person who's operating it does not have the skills and talent, it will be a waste of time.